# ORDER table data using 'DISTINCT'

Tags: sql, postgresql, distinct

Im using postgress pgadmin as my database. In my application I need to search details from a specific table.

For that I used method like below.

---

```
SELECT DISTINCT xx , yy
FROM (
  SELECT xx , yy
) total
```

Here I used  **DISTINCT** to remove duplicate entries. But when I use that, it will sort the filtered data according to **tableID**.

So is there any method to remove duplicates & filetere data without sorting them according to **tableID** ?

Comment: If you don't give an `ORDER BY` the data is **not** sorted, even if it appears sorted

Comment: Please add sample data to your question.

Comment: The **only** way to get a guaranteed sort order is to use `ORDER BY`. There is no alternative.

Comment: And, of course, you need to clearly define what sort order you want, *when considering that the original data may have been present in multiple rows*. E.g if you have three rows, A, B, A and your `DISTINCT` reduces that to `A` and `B`, should the `A` row appear before or after the `B` row?

Comment: Not only is your example invalid in the first place, but there is no column named tableID in it.  So if it were valid, it would still wouldn't be an example of the thing you are trying to describe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not specify any order the rows will generally be returned in the order that they were inserted into the table, but this is not garanteed.
You can specify the order with `ORDER BY` as you need

- sort by xx then yy, with `ORDER BY xx, yy` or the opposite with `ORDER BY yy, zz`
- sort smallest first by default or with ASC
- sort largest first with DESC
  for example `ORDER BY xx DESC` will return the row with the largest value of `xx` first.
- sort by functions for example `ORDER BY x / y`

```
SELECT DISTINCT xx , yy
FROM (
  SELECT xx , yy
) total
ORDER BY xx , yy;
```